# Gotta steal power from USB micro

Tags: power, led, usb

I play a fair bit on my Xbox one at home and I want to make it more personal, I have a translucent controller that I want to put some 3.8 V LEDs in but without external wiring. So this might be more of a circuit question about the connection, but how can I draw that power? the connection is rated at 5 V, I don't think the controller takes more than 1 V. So I just want to take some leads and hook it up to a PCB with the necessary stuff and then put the LEDs in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the controller will take 5 V if it is powered by USB. (It may not consume much power or may not draw much current, but the voltage is usually constant on such devices). You should be able to wire your 5V LED circuit in parallel to the rest of the USB circuit as long as it also does not draw much current either. Solder your LED circuit to the GND and 5V leads where they come into the controller without modifying the controller's circuit at all. Ensure you design your LED circuit to be powered by 5 V -- you may need to add some resistors.